# Graficos con canvasJS no muestra - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Estoy tratando de correr este ejemplo :

https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/json-data-api-ajax-chart/

Sin tener resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si trae datos con el `console.log(result)` de mi Ajax

```
[{"Total":"2","fecha":"2017-11-20"},{"Total":"3","fecha":"2017-11-21"},{"Total":"3","fecha":"2017-11-22"},{"Total":"2","fecha":"2017-11-23"}]
```

Este es mi JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseurl + 'Graficos/obtener_evaluacion',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var resultado = $.trim(result);
            console.log(result);
            addData(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });

    var dataPoints = [];
    function addData(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            dataPoints.push({
                x: data[i].fecha,
                y: data[i].Total
            });
        }
        chart.render();

    }

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        theme: "light2",
        title: {
            text: "Daily Sales Data"
        },
        axisY: {
            title: "Units",
            titleFontSize: 24
        },
        data: [{
                type: "column",
                yValueFormatString: "#,### Units",
                dataPoints: dataPoints
            }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Y cual es tú error ? y el ejemplo funcionable ?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian lee el post :/

Comment: Okey, te publicaré la respuesta

Comment: @Marcos muchas gracias por tu comentario, efectivamente ya tengo la solucion, de todas maneras muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que publicaste, que además visite en la web oficial, está bastante mal hecho, ya que el principal error es que la ejecución es sincrona, por lo cual cuando se crea la variable chart y se le asigna dataPoints, ese array de datos, en verdad llega vacio, puedes comprobarlo haciendo una función dentro del array chart y mostrando el supuesto dataPoints.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",draw);
  function draw(){
    var toData = [{"Total":"2","fecha":"2017-11-20"},{"Total":"3","fecha":"2017-11-21"},{"Total":"3","fecha":"2017-11-22"},{"Total":"2","fecha":"2017-11-23"}],
        dataPoints = [];
    toData.forEach( statistic => {
    dataPoints.push({x: new Date(statistic.fecha), y: Number(statistic.Total)});  
    });
    var nosync = () => {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 theme: "light2",
 title: {
  text: "Daily Sales Data"
 },
 axisY: {
  title: "Units",
  titleFontSize: 24
 },
 data: [{
  type: "column",
  yValueFormatString: "#,### Units",
  dataPoints: dataPoints
 }]
   });
   return chart;   
   };   
   var _ini = nosync(dataPoints); _ini.render(); 
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```